# A bookmarklet to use a portion of the current URL in a new URL

Tags: javascript, url, subdomain, bookmarklet, tumblr

I'm wanting to make a bookmarklet that would change a webpage from

http://user.tumblr.com/post/123456789
to
http://user.tumblr.com/liked/by/user

with just a click. I'm usually alright at frankensteining code together, and I've been looking at the Tumblr manual reblog button that uses "window.location" along with
[Bookmarklet to edit current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689553/bookmarklet-to-edit-current-url)
and
[Replace end characters of current URL with bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972457/replace-end-characters-of-current-url-with-bookmarklet)

I can't see anything useable that would extract a subdomain into a variable and then place it in a new URL. I did stumble across this code:

```
^http://([^.]+)\.domain\.com
```

But I have no idea what that means or how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for, but I use as I have multiple instances of my site and what bookmarks to keep me in the same instance regardless of port or protocol.

New Tab

```
javascript:(function(){window.open(location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+':'+location.port+'/liked/by/user')})();
```

Current Tab

```
javascript:(function(){window.location.assign(location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+':'+location.port+'/liked/by/user')})();
```

EDIT: Forgot to put code blocks

Comment: That works well, is there any way to detect the subdomain (location.subdomain doesn't work) and replace 'user' with it?